# which is better code for maintaining the database and why?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Multiple Tables...

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pictures` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `propPictures` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `picture_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `property_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pictures` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`property_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

????

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Will every picture have exactly one `property_id`? If so then a single table is fine.

Answer (score 2):

A Property can and probably will have multiple pictures, so what you want is a property table and then a picture table that includes property id and has a foreign key to the porperty table.

Incidentally ID is a terrible choice for the id field. It creates problems with reporting and can cause accidental join problems. Two tables should almost never use the same name for fields which mean something different. Use tablenameID instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're suggesting table1 for pictures, and table2 for any properties it may have.  This would usually be better than a single table design as it makes it easy to handle any given picture having, 0, 1, or many more properties.

Comment: sorry for making it look confusing to you. the entity name property refers to a property table. actually i am building an application for real estate.

Answer (score 0):

With a one-to-one relationship between pictures.id and property_id, a single table would suffice. If this relationship changes to one to many, a second table will become necessary to relate the one pictures.id to the many property ids.